# Sub-Domain on Main Domain route to other Directory

Tags: linux, domain, subdomain, apache-2.4

I would like to use my main domain for my main site when it has no sub domain, and when it has the sub domain billing.mydomain.co.uk it should redirect to a seperate directory on the server instead of the directory that the main server content is hosted on.

This is what I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomaindir

   ServerName billing.mydomain.co.uk
   ServerAlias *.billing.mydomain.co.uk

   ErrorLog "/var/log/mydomain.in-error_log"
   CustomLog "/var/log/mydomain.in-access_log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

This currently displays nothing.

Everything is enabled properly as I already have other main domains directing to other directories, I just can't seem to get the subdomain to redirect, it simply displays a no server found at this address message.

Comment: Does DNS for billing.mydomain.co.uk point to your web server?

Comment: Good point my friend, good point. Doh, never even thought of that. I'm an idiot. Thanks. I'll delete the thread.

Comment: Glad that helped.  No, don't delete the thread.  Someone else may benefit from it in the future.